# How prove this inequality $(\sum_{k=1}^{3n}a_{k})^3\ge 27n^2\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}a_{n+k}a_{2n+k}$

Tags: inequality

> let $$0\le a_{1}\le a_{2}\le \cdots\le a_{3n}$$   show that
>   $$\left(a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3}+\cdots+a_{3n-1}+a_{3n}\right)^3\ge 27n^2\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}a_{n+k}a_{2n+k}$$

we  know when  $n=1$，this is 
$$(a+b+c)^3\ge 27abc$$ this is AM-GM inequality.
because $$a+b+c\ge 3\sqrt[3]{abc}$$
$$\Longrightarrow (a+b+c)^3\ge 27abc$$

when $n=2$, then we have
$$(a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3}+\cdots+a_{6})^3\ge 108(a_{1}a_{3}a_{5}+a_{2}a_{4}a_{6})$$
this inequality maybe can use AM-GM inequality to solve it.and For general How prove it? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Group into 3 terms. So

$$
(a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_{3n})^3 >= (a_1+a_{n+1}+a_{2n+1})^3+\cdots+(a_n+a_{2n}+a_{3n})^3
$$

Then use AM-GM for RHS terms. Are you sure the RHS is $27n^2$ and not $27n$ ?

Comment: Hello,It's $27n^2$ is also hold,if RHS is $27n$ is clear AM-GM,